# methodtest.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `pritnf'

Tags: c, warnings, int

So im trying to work with methods for the first time in c and when i compile i get this as an output

```
gcc -o methodtest methodtest.o
methodtest.o: In function `main':
methodtest.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `pritnf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [methodtest] Error 1
```

the code looks like this

```
void main(void)
{
  int num, num2, num3;
  num = 3;
  num2 = 2;
  num3 = 1;
  int ans = addem(num, num2, num3);
  pritnf("%d\n", ans);
}

int addem(int num, int num2, int num3)
{
  return(num+num2+num3);
}
```

why why am i getting this error or whatever it is?

Comment: @Anonymous: I think you mean `#include <stido.h>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a typo:

`pritnf` should be `printf`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the printf typo, you can't allocate variables in the middle of main like that. In C, all variables must be allocated at the beginning of the scope (directly after the "{" ).

Though perhaps you have set the compiler to compile the code as C++?

Comment: C99 allows this, and many C compilers allow this as an extension even if they don't claim C99 support. Unfortunately, MSVC is one that doesn't support declarations mixed with statements when compiling C code.